# Sonata admin: list one to many in edit page

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I have a many many to many relation in Sonata (two one to many relations to be exact), Brand and Retailer.
In the Brand admin Edit page, I want to display all the retailers as a list (so just a read only version), instead of having the normal edit (at the moment, on this brand edit page, I can manage the relationship between this brand and retailers - add a new one, delete an existing one).

I tried to explore two routes so far:

1. Edit page will load a custom twig
2. Using a custom field type for this field only

My issue is, with both options, I didn't manage to get to a solution
So here is what I have done:

1 - Loading a custom edit twig:

```
services:
  xx_brand.admin.brand_brand:
    calls:
        - [ setTemplate, [edit, xxBrandBundle:Admin:base_edit.html.twig]]
```

On this case, base_edit is an exact copy of the sonata `base_edit`, but it loads my custom `base_edit_form`:

```
{% use 'xxBrandBundle:Admin:base_edit_form.html.twig' with form as parentForm %}
```

From here I can exclude the default rendering of the `retailers`, but can't find a way to then render it as I want, as I am not sure how the `retailers` entity is managed here:

```
{% if admin.formfielddescriptions[field_name] is defined and field_name != 'retailers' %}
  {{ form_row(form[field_name])}}
{% else %}
  <ul>
    <li>retailer1</li>
    <li>retailer2</li>
  </ul>
{% endif %}
```

---

2 - For the approach of a custom field type, I tried to follow the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_custom_field_type.html)

- Creating the `Bundle/Form/Type/ListType.php`
- Creating the `/BrandBundle/Resources/views/form/list.html.twig`
- Using the `ListType` in `configureFormFields`:

  `use XX\BrandBundle\Form\Type\ListType;
    ...
    ->add('retailers', 'ListType');`

But I then get an error `XX\BrandBundle\Form\Type\ListType`

So basically, because I couldn't get it to work, are any of these two options good to solve my issue ?
If so, could anyone please advice on what I am missing there ??
Any help will be very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sonata_type_model_list`: https://sonata-project.org/bundles/doctrine-orm-admin/master/doc/reference/form_field_definition.html#example

Like so:

```
class BrandAdmin extends Admin
{
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            ->add('retailer', 'sonata_type_model_list', array(
            'btn_add'       => false,
            'btn_delete'    => false,           
        ));

    }
}
```